# Is It true that Ravana and Mandodari never had a fight between them?

Tags: ramayana, ravana, mandodari

I asked this because of an incident happened to me in the past. I was coming back from Vaishno Devi (Pilgrimage), and it was the Dusshera (Ravana's Death Anniversary) so I visited nearby big field in which Ravan was going to be burned. After it burned all people rush towards it and collected all the burned leftover sticks of the statue. I haven't seen this collection of sticks(bamboo sticks) practice elsewhere. At least not in my own state. When I asked a person why are they collecting sticks from the Ravana's statue's leftovers, he replied that it is a good thing to be kept at home as it prevents fighting between the married couples. He explained me the reason that is the Ravan and Mandodari never fought. So is this true?

Comment: Well, I think they fought over whether Sita should be freed.  I think Ravana and Mandodari not fighting is just folklore.  People take statements like "Ravana had some positive aspects apart from kidnapping Sita" and then exaggerate his good qualities.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Can you share the Link from Ramayana where Ravana and Mandodari ought over whether Sita should be freed? I guess that can be posted as Answer too...as the argument in Question is not correct as per scriptural reference.

Comment: I hadn't heard any such story where there is an argument between Ravan And Mandodari over Sita